# Why is my background grey?

Tags: packages

I had written a curriculum vitae with LateX about 10 years ago and dug up the old template to update the document. I am typesetting on my mac now and the results look kinda out of whack.

The background is grey.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tabularx}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont\rmfamily\scshape}

% define footer
\cofoot{\footnotesize\so\addr \\
\footnotesize\so{ {\Large\Letter} NAME} \  \footnotesize\so{ {\Large\Telefon}  PHONE}}

\geometry{letterpaper,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,headheight=0in,headsep=0in,footskip=.3in}

\setlength{\headheight}{1.1\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0in}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
\setlength{\topsep}{0in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Name and contact information
\newcommand{\name}{NAME}
\newcommand{\addr}{ADDR}
\newcommand{\phone}{PHONE}
\newcommand{\email}{EMAIL}

\newenvironment{cvsection}[1]{
    \vspace{32pt}\hspace{16 pt}\textbf{\normalsize{#1}}\vspace{-11pt}
    
    \textcolor{gray}{\rule\textwidth{0.1pt}}\vspace{16pt}
    
}


\newenvironment{cvitem}[3]{

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.67\textwidth}p{0.03\textwidth}}
\hspace{32 pt}\textsc{\small#1} & \small#2
\begin{itemize} 
\scriptsize#3
\end{itemize} &
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{-6pt}

}

\newcommand{\cvsmallitem}[2]{

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.67\textwidth}p{0.03\textwidth}}
\hspace{32 pt}\textsc{\small#1} & \small#2 &
\end{tabularx}

}

%--------------------Beginn Document----------------------------
\begin{document}

\vspace{0pt}
\textsc{\begin{center}\Huge\so\name\end{center}} 
\textsc{\begin{center}\huge\so{Curriculum Vitae}\end{center}} 
\textsc{\begin{center}\large\so{FEbruary 2012}\end{center}}

%--------------------Sections-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Data
...

\end{document}
```

these are my initial setting and this is the first part of the output:
[image]

Additionally, special German characters are not being **displayed correctly**.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I cannot reproduce the grey background color with your example.

Comment: About the special chars --- I bet that the editor silently changed the encoding to `utf8` when opening the file, try switch `latin1` to `utf8`. (been there...)

Comment: @Rmano not so silently, actually quite explicitly :D will see if I can cahnge it back. Thx for the pointer.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ very strange. It's actually the firs time that I am using the editor (TexShop) and also the first time that I am using Tex on Mac. Wow ... It's just a previw thing I guess, when saving all is fine. Thx so much

Comment: @Rmano Hmmm,  No clue how to change it back, always jumps back to IsoLatin9. I'll keep trying

Comment: Are you using Dark Mode? If so, many editor/front ends use a gray background to lore glare. Does it print ok?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Jupp prints fine. Wow, people on the StackExchange are really super friendly. Appreciate that. The only thing I got to solve now is the special characters.

Comment: If your file is now utf8 the simply remove the inputenc line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that did it! Thanks a lot! I have no idea why I had it even in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too use TeXShop on my Macs and if you're using the systemwide Dark Mode, the TeXShop Preview window takes on a gray color. I just noticed I'm also using TeXShop's DarkTheme theme. I haven't tested whether or not this theme causes the gray Preview background when not using the systemwide Dark Mode. The point is nothing is wrong with your document or with TeXShop. It's a Dark Mode issue.

Comment: You can change the background color in the Preview window under the Themes tab of TeXShop->Preferences.

Comment: Thanks. I should have pointed that out.